# Как из активити обратиться к элементу view, подключаемому в адаптере

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть данный экран приложения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Панель с `SwitchCompact` лежит в активити, все, что ниже, принадлежит `RecycleView`. При переключении `Switch`'ей нужно определенные элементы view списка делать `GONE`. Как обратиться из активити к элементам view адаптера?

Comment: У Вас же есть адаптер, который хранит данные? Вот туда добавьте флажки и обновляйте их. А список сам себя обновит, когда сможет.